# When is this not true? $\forall n \in \mathbb N: (1-1/n < x \wedge 1-1/n < 1 \implies 1 \leq x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I can't not see why the following implication

$$\forall n \in \mathbb N: (1-1/n < x \wedge 1-1/n < 1 \implies 1 \leq x)$$

is not true for all natural numbers $n$ and where $x$ is a real number.

I would say that the implication is true!

Comment: I think it misses a piece of information. What about $x$? For all $x$ in the reals?

Comment: Well, if you assume $\forall n \in \mathbb N: 1-1/n < x$, than it's clear that $x$ can not be less that $1$.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue, which is that $x$ isn't quantified. I suspect there should be $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ in front of the colon, there.

Comment: What is the scope of the $\forall$? Is it $(\forall \ldots) \implies \ldots$ or $\forall n :(\ldots \implies \ldots)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It's is the last one. I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you write:

> If $1−1/n<x$ for all $n∈N$, then $x$ can never be less than $1$."

Not true. For example, pick $n=1$. Then $1−1/n = 1-1 = 0$. So, $0<x$ ... but $x$ can still be smaller than $1$

In fact, for *any* $n$ you have that $1-1/n<1$, and hence you can always find some $x$ such that $1-1/n < x <1$, so those would all be counterexamples to the claim.

Answer (score 1):

First of all an implication $p\rightarrow q$ is false if and only if $p$ holds but $q$ does not hold at the same time.

Now,
The statement $1>1-\frac{1}{n}$ is true for every 
$n\in\mathbb{N}$. Yet the implication is false
becasue there exists an $j\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$x>1-\frac{1}{j}$ but $x<1$. Take $j=2$ and $x=3/4$ as a counterexample.

The implcation statement is not to be confused with the TRUE statement 
 $x>1-\frac{1}{n},\; \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\Longrightarrow x\geq 1$. One can prove this by contradiction. For if $x<1$ then there exists an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\leq 1-\frac{1}{m}$ which contradicts that $x>1-\frac{1}{n},\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $x>1-\frac{1}{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Longrightarrow x \geq 1$. This was actually what I was thinking. I shouldn't have used notation that I'm not 100 % confident with. Also, I have proved this by using the following: $\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: a<n$

Comment: Exactly. ∀a∈R∃n∈N:a<n is what is used in the argument by contradiction. Notice that you should accept the answer by clicking "accept this answer".

Answer (score 0):

$n=1$ and $x=0.5$ is a counterexample.

Comment: No it's not. If $1-1/n < x$ for all $n \in  \mathbb N$, then $x$ can never be less than 1.

Comment: What is the negation of the statement you gave in your post?

Comment: The negation is not relevant.

Comment: @Xenusi Of course it is, if you prove the negation then you've disproved the statement, and your question was "why is this statement not true". What is the negation of the statement?